# Kusto command to display engine type (V2 or V3)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there any Kusto command (not through Azure portal) to display engine version (V2 or V3 etc) ? The command `.show version` doesn't provide this piece of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the default engine version configuration using following command:

```
.show database <DB-NAME> policy sharding 
| project IsEngineV3 = parse_json(Policy).UseShardEngine
```

If returned value is 'True' - the engine is configured to ingest new data using 'Shard Engine' (aka Kusto Engine v3)